# Unexpected validation on User model with devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

An application using devise has configured the login with a specific attribute:
`config.authentication_keys = [:login_name]`

This attribute is defined via a User method where a login requires **either** an email or a mobile.
The latter being distinct from '0' in order to allow a populated attribute that can be then compared for uniqueness.

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :authentication_keys => [:login_name]

  validate  :at_least_one_identifier
  validates :mobile, uniqueness: { scope: :nation_id, message: (I18n.t('user.define_one_mobile_per_nation')) }, if: -> { mobile != 0 }
  validates :email, uniqueness: true, if: -> { email.present? } 

  def at_least_one_identifier
    if [self.email, self.mobile].reject(&:blank?).size == 0
      errors[:base] << (I18n.t('user.define_email_or_mobile'))
    end
  end
```

When running a test however, debugging the process

```
    login_name = '+19991112200'
    user = User.new(mobile: 9991112200, login_name: login_name, password: '11111111', password_confirmation: '11111111' )
user.valid?
puts user.errors.first.to_s
```

identifies the following error:

`activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.email.blank`

This is not a validation which should fire.

While [this wiki](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address) suggests over-writing a method, the method's name `find_for_database_authentication`  is not [indicative of a specific validation](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address#overwrite-devises-find_for_database_authentication-method-in-user-model) and speaks more to the login action than the sign_up process: "change the behavior of the login action"

There are no validations regarding `email` within the user model.  The suspicion is that Devise is setting this requirement, but where?

Comment: The validatable module clearly has it...https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/8593801130f2df94a50863b5db535c272b00efe1/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb.  I don't see that option in your user model.  But the authenticatable module does as well...https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/8593801130f2df94a50863b5db535c272b00efe1/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb Though not as obviously.

Comment: Oh the irony.  the following was seen as uncovered by the test suite for the User model & there were no calls to it.  So I pulled it out.  `  def email_required?    false   end`.  Reversing that move and test flows anew.  model requires a comment there!